# Why can't I Dot a matrix with itself

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, warning-messages

`x1.x1` in a 2×2 matrix gets a tensor error. Mathematica says it does not keep track of row or column, but I have spent hours trying to figure out what I have to do to square this matrix. Same error when in use `MatrixPower`.

`ximi.ximi` produces this error

> Dot::dotsh: Tensors {{{-0.347315},{-0.19314}},{{-0.154175},{-8.37453*10^-19}}} and {{{-0.347315},{-0.19314}},{{-0.154175},{-8.37453*10^-19}}} have incompatible shapes. >>

Comment: You have too many parenthesis. Resolve the curly brackets around the inner most scalar.

Answer (score 4):

> i have spent hours trying to figure out what i have to do to square this matrix

Not really. Really? Why didn't you open the help browser and typed `Matrix` in the search-bar? You mentioned [`MatrixPower`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MatrixPower.html) so look at the help page at the very very first example. It is exactly what you want: a square matrix 2x2 to a power of 10

```
MatrixPower[{{1, 1}, {1, 2}}, 10]
```

Even without any experience, you should be able to deduce that this is the matrix

```
{
  {1, 1},
  {1, 2}
}
```

The whole matrix is a list of rows. Each row is a list of numbers. Now look at the tensor of your error message

```
{
  {{-0.347315},{-0.19314}},
  {{-0.154175},{-8.37453*10^-19}}
}
```

This is not a 2x2 matrix. Let's get rid of the additional braces and try again

```
MatrixPower[{{-0.347315, -0.19314}, {-0.154175, -8.37453*10^-19}}, 5]
(* {{-0.0109679, -0.00506291}, {-0.00404149, -0.00186347}} *)
```

### Answer to your comments

> ok, so apparently my problem starts sooner than this. the values in the matrix are the means of 4 vectors. i simply named the means, say a,b,c,d and said x1= then used the template matrix, and put in the 4 variable names. it comes out in that format. i am calculating Battacharyya distance on many objects with many observations and many clusters. it has to be automatic, so that when i enter in 150 observations, the calculations get done. how can i take the mean of a vector and enter it in so that it will calculate as a matrix?

Assume you have 4 vectors a,b,c and d

```
{a, b, c, d} = RandomReal[1, {4, 6}];
```

Now you want to calculate the mean of each vector and put it in a matrix. You can use `Map` for this that *maps a function to a nested structure*. Usually, you map a function over the elements of a list, but you can specify at which *level* the function needs to be applied:

```
Map[Mean, {{a, b}, {c, d}}, {2}]
(* {{0.416564, 0.610657}, {0.491622, 0.466826}} *)
```

This reads: Map the function `Mean` over the nested list (aka matrix) at the level 2.

Comment: ok, so apparently my problem starts sooner than this.  the values in the matrix are the means of 4 vectors.  i simply named the means, say a,b,c,d and said x1= then used the template matrix, and put in the 4 variable names.  it comes out in that format.  i am calculating Battacharyya distance on many objects with many observations and many clusters.  it has to be automatic, so that when i enter in 150 observations, the calculations get done.  how can i take the mean of a vector and enter it in so that it will calculate as a matrix?  and thanks for the answer too.  but i am still stuck.

Comment: In[342]:= Clear[xi, \[Mu]i]

xi = {mn\[CapitalDelta]x1\[Mu]1, mn\[CapitalDelta]x1\[Mu]2}
\[Mu]i = {mn\[CapitalDelta]x2\[Mu]1, mn\[CapitalDelta]x2\[Mu]2}
xx = xi.\[Mu]i
% // MatrixForm

Out[359]= {{-0.347315}, {-0.19314}}

Out[360]= {{-0.154175}, {-8.37453*10^-19}}

During evaluation of In[359]:= Dot::dotsh: Tensors {{-0.347315},{-0.19314}} and {{-0.154175},{-8.37453*10^-19}} have incompatible shapes. >>

Out[361]= {{-0.347315}, {-0.19314}}.{{-0.154175}, {-8.37453*10^-19}}
these look the same to me

Comment: ok, i think i got it.
In[365]:= xi = {Sqrt[
  mn\[CapitalDelta]x1\[Mu]1.mn\[CapitalDelta]x1\[Mu]1], Sqrt[
  mn\[CapitalDelta]x1\[Mu]2.mn\[CapitalDelta]x1\[Mu]2]}
\[Mu]i = {Sqrt[mn\[CapitalDelta]x2\[Mu]1.mn\[CapitalDelta]x2\[Mu]1], 
  Sqrt[mn\[CapitalDelta]x2\[Mu]2.mn\[CapitalDelta]x2\[Mu]2]}
xx = xi.\[Mu]i
% // MatrixForm

Out[365]= {0.347315, 0.19314}

Out[366]= {0.154175, 8.37453*10^-19}

Out[367]= 0.0535473
the dialog helped

Comment: @DBeamer Let me make a small addition to my answer. 2min..

Comment: @DBeamer Done. When you want to share code in comments, please surround it by backticks: ` ``code`` `. Otherwise the code gets completely messed up.